# Help in deconstructing a sentence

Tags: commas, slang, offensive-language, australian-english

This was a question posed by a friend. I'm myself curious of the answer. I apologize for the explicit content (I left it as is to remove ambiguity). I pretty sure that 'a yuppy fu@k' is a compound noun in the local slang, but I'm not sure, just like the author of the question, of the nature of the second instance of 'fu@k'. Any feedback will be appreciated.

"Some graffiti I saw in a back lane off Acland Street, St.Kilda:

I'm a yuppy fuck, fuck.

The phrase has stayed with me because of the use of the comma. Is the final word a noun or a verb? Is it an exclamation?"

Comment: There's aboslutely no way to tell. Read it as you like.

Comment: I would venture a guess that the overall meaning of the sentence is analogous to what it would be if the final word were replaced by something like ‘‘sir’’. In other words, the author is proclaiming their identity, but then is implying, ‘‘If you’re reading this, then you’re a fu@k too.’’

Comment: I can't help reading 'fu@k' as 'foo-ack'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the first instance of 'fuck' is used in its noun meaning of 'contemptible or ridiculous person', like dumb fuck, sick fuck, mean fuck, etc. The second instance seems to be an exclamation, and might have had 'it' appended, making the word a transitive verb. I don't think you need to coyly hide behind 'fu@k', especially since you showed the "f-word" in full in your quotation of the graffiti.

Comment: I seem to have upset someone.